# TTL "radio-button" using priority encoder and latch

Tags: ttl, encoder, button, latch

I'm liking this site and I am not always using it to just throw a question but to develop ideas all the way. First time I did that was on StackOverflow [I need JSZip and gzip for my web page, and JSZip has all the ingredients, but hides them in ways I can't crack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486254/i-need-jszip-and-gzip-for-my-web-page-and-jszip-has-all-the-ingredients-but-hi) or just yesterday when [Debugging a battery charger circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/467058/debugging-a-battery-charger-circuit) I thoroughly asked myself to the solution.

So now I want to build a radio-button function in TTL. That is, I have here up to 8 sources only one of which can output data on a bus. Instead of running 8 lines, I want to select the devices' output enable by using only 3-lines output select address. The same principle would work for a data source selector.

To be clear: I know how to build the selector, with either a n-to-1 m-bit selector chip or on a bus, each device has a three-state output with the enable line fed from a A=B output of a comparator which listens to the encoded 3 bit device address. But the project here right now is only to allow a human to select one of the 8 devices by pushing one of 8 buttons.

My raw material is the 74LS148 8-line to 3-line priority encoder, and the 74LS375 4 x bistable latch.

My idea is this: the latch saves the 3 bit device address from the 8-line-to-3-line priority encoder which is operated by momentary push buttons. The push buttons are not locking because I don't want a mechanical radio-button setup but do it in TTL.

If there was a little DIP switch form factor rotary selector I might use that too, but my supplier only has that in the size you would use for a 1980s stereo component deck as the input selector. I want it smaller. (It's actually fun to think about though. How would I encode such a mechanical selector to digital? In that case I wouldn't even need a latch, just the priority encoder would work.)

So here is that 74LS148 pinout

[image: 74LS148 pinout]

and the function table

[image].

First I need to disentangle the excessive negation that's going on in some of these TTL chips. Consistently those priority encoders and the decoders (3-to-8, or 2-to-4) consistently have these individual lines inverted. It's like they were built for your typical chip select signal chip select (CS) or write enable (WE) lines that are typically active low. But in my case, I don't want to use extra inverters. So that means I sort the function table by output word:

```
OUTPUT    INPUT (active low)
# A2 1 0    #
- ------  -----
0  L L L    7
1  L L H    6
2  L H L    5
3  L H H    4
4  H L L    3
5  H L H    2
6  H H L    1
7  H H H    0
```

It doesn't matter that the chip pinout nomenclature labels the input pins 0 - 7. That they are active low is not a problem, we just use 10 kΩ pull-up resistors to Vcc and then the push button short to GND. Easy. And this gives us a straight non-inverted output from this chip. The input EI we will simply tie to GND.

Now comes the radio-button latching behavior. We need to use a toggle signal that informs us that a button has been pressed. That's what we have the two additional outputs G5 and E0 for. G5 is low if and only if one of the input lines are low, while E0 is low if none of the input lines are low.

And my idea is to use GS or E0 for the latch. That is, if I am lucky the timing behavior will be thus that either G5 will be low *after* the encoder value has already been set or E0 will become low before the encoder value has been changed already. I'd consider ourselves really unlucky if this chip would make us miss the boat in both directions!

There is actually something in the data sheet which is telling us about this behavior.

[image]

but I don't understand this. What is exactly in-phase and out of phase I cannot decipher from this table. However, when I look at the gates:

[image]

I get an intuition that E0 will be switched through faster than anything else, because everything else has more gates, especially the addresses. This means, ideally I trigger the falling edge of the latch by the E0 line as it should fall before the A outputs change.

Here is the 74LS375 latch, which I chose over the old '75 because it has the standard Vcc / GND pins.

[image: 74LS375 pin out]

So with that, my wiring circuit goes like that ... NOTE: the circuit tool crapped up on me, I think more and more they should not be promoted here until they allow saving your work without paying, I lost an hour of design work. Now using paper and pencil:

[image: Radio Button TTL circuit sketch]

So, there I go. Do I need to de-bounce this? I prefer not to and I don't think so, because the latch should hold the key pressed even if the bounce does a rapid-fire it will still be from the same button, hence there won't be rapid state changes.

Now let's see if I can build it and if it works for me. I will add picture from the breadboard once I am done.

And tada! Instant success. 
[image: Finished breadboard prototype, working.]
So here I have it built with 3 buttons, from left to right values 0, 1, and 7. It was an instant success. No debugging needed of any kind. Some minor glitching was observed but nothing that is so bad that it would be unusable for my mini-computer front panel console project.

Here is a demo video. [Demo of TTL "radio-button" using encoder and latch.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H609FqE8wh8)

Comment: Welcome. I *think* you are looking for a 8-input data selector such as a 74HC151. You feed it a 3 bit address to select one input. Using a binary counter such as a 74HC161 you can scroll through all 8 inputs. Drive the counter with a debounced push button switch. Except for debounce you will have little need for resistors or capacitors. The 74xx148 is meant to handle software/hardware interrupts.

Comment: Actually it was a good point you made, in that my goal wasn't really clearly described at the outset. I have tried to clarify it now.

Comment: _"Some minor glitching was observed"_ - you might consider adding a capacitor (~100nF-1uF) across the supply pins of each IC. Interesting project, but this site is _only_ for asking questions. Do you have one?

Comment: @BruceAbbott "but this site is only for asking questions. Do you have one?" -- haha, I couldn't figure out the switching characteristics table. I guess I got all these down-votes because of not asking a question. OTOH, I'm not concerned, because I could have stopped at any point and just be lazy and ask. But I preferred to just work it through myself, guess an answer and try it out. This isn't found in The TTL Cookbook nor did I find it elsewhere on Google. Now, if anybody wants to know how to do electronic radio buttons without throwing an Arduino at it, they have the answer.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question, but you shouldn't put the answer in the question (if you do answer it properly, please include a neatly drawn schematic of your solution - don't expect us to trace the breadboard wiring or watch a YouTube video). And this site is not your personal blog. If you want to brainstorm or show people what you are working on then do it in a forum such as the [EEVblog Electronics Community](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/).